# Error: TimestampType can not accept object while creating a Spark dataframe from a list

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a dataframe from the following list:

```
data = [(1,'abc','2020-08-20 10:00:00', 'I'),
(1,'abc','2020-08-20 10:01:00', 'U'),
(1,'abc','2020-08-21 10:02:00', 'U'),
(2,'pqr','2020-08-20 10:00:00', 'I'),
(2,'pqr','2020-08-20 10:01:00', 'U'),
(2,'pqr','2020-08-21 10:02:00', 'D'),
(3,'rst','2020-08-20 10:00:00', 'I'),
(3,'rst','2020-08-20 10:01:00', 'U'),
(3,'rst','2020-08-21 10:02:00', 'U')]
```

I am running the following code to create a dataframe from this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
mySchema = StructType([StructField("key", IntegerType()),
                      StructField("name", StringType()),
                      StructField("ts", TimestampType()),
                      StructField("cdc_flag", StringType())])

df_raw = spark.createDataFrame(data, mySchema)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: field ts: TimestampType can not accept object '2020-08-20 10:00:00' in type <class 'str'>
```

I tried changing the data type to DateType also. But getting the same error.

Please note that, I am trying to understand if this way of implementing the schema is possible or not.
I think I can use withColumn and cast this ts column and drop the original column to handle this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is justified because [`TimestampType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.types.TimestampType.html) expects a `Timestamp` type and not a `str`. This can be derived by using `java.sql.Timestamp` in Scala and `datetime` in Python.

You just need to define your `data` like:

```python
from datetime import datetime

data = [(1,'abc',datetime.strptime('2020-08-20 10:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'I'),
(1,'abc',datetime.strptime('2020-08-20 10:01:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'U'),
(1,'abc',datetime.strptime('2020-08-21 10:02:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'U'),
(2,'pqr',datetime.strptime('2020-08-20 10:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'I'),
(2,'pqr',datetime.strptime('2020-08-20 10:01:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'U'),
(2,'pqr',datetime.strptime('2020-08-21 10:02:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'D'),
(3,'rst',datetime.strptime('2020-08-20 10:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'I'),
(3,'rst',datetime.strptime('2020-08-20 10:01:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'U'),
(3,'rst',datetime.strptime('2020-08-21 10:02:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'U')]


spark.createDataFrame(data, mySchema).show()
#+---+----+-------------------+--------+
#|key|name|                 ts|cdc_flag|
#+---+----+-------------------+--------+
#|  1| abc|2020-08-20 10:00:00|       I|
#|  1| abc|2020-08-20 10:01:00|       U|
#|  1| abc|2020-08-21 10:02:00|       U|
#|  2| pqr|2020-08-20 10:00:00|       I|
#|  2| pqr|2020-08-20 10:01:00|       U|
#|  2| pqr|2020-08-21 10:02:00|       D|
#|  3| rst|2020-08-20 10:00:00|       I|
#|  3| rst|2020-08-20 10:01:00|       U|
#|  3| rst|2020-08-21 10:02:00|       U|
#+---+----+-------------------+--------+


spark.createDataFrame(data, mySchema).printSchema()
#root
# |-- key: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
# |-- cdc_flag: string (nullable = true)
```