# Create mock timestamp value

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to make a mock DataFrame like so:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType, TimestampType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkSession.builder.appName('Testing').getOrCreate()

data = [("FIX", 100.0, 0.01, 0.04, 0.05, '2022-10-31 16:00:00.05'),
        ("FLT", 1000.0, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, '2022-09-21 08:59:00.00'),
        ("MIX", 10000.0, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, '2022-08-15 13:25:16.00'),
        ("MIX", 15000.0, 0.04, 0.01, 0.04, '2022-06-03 19:27:03.00')
        ]

schema = StructType([StructField("type", StringType(), nullable=True),
                     StructField("remaining_amt", DoubleType(), nullable=True),
                     StructField("fix_rt", DoubleType(), nullable=True),
                     StructField("flt_rt", DoubleType(), nullable=True),
                     StructField("spread", DoubleType(), nullable=True),
                     StructField("end_date", TimestampType(), nullable=True)
                     ])
mock_df = sc.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
```

But I get the following error:

`TypeError: field fecha_vencimiento: TimestampType can not accept object '2022-10-31 16:00:00.05' in type <class 'str'>`

How can I write a hardcoded timestamp value?

Comment: Hi Eduardo, unfortunately Spark doesn't support this out of the box. You need to explicitly define a Timestamp in order for it to work. Have you checked out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68435677/error-timestamptype-can-not-accept-object-while-creating-a-spark-dataframe-from)?

Comment: you're passing a string, so you can read it as string. spark is intelligent enough to treat it as a ts when needed -- as in you can use datetime functions on that string given it is in default format (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`). OR, you can run it through `to_timestamp` function post reading the string ts.

Comment: @GustavoPuma what would you do in the same scenario but trying to parse a file? this would mean it can't be read directly am I right?